# Get model data from Razor passed to knockout file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I am working on a page that is getting it's data from the database models. I do not want to do an ajax call to get a controller to turn this into json and then manipulate it. We are doing a lot more things with the initial controller action and it would be a lot more work to modify the action. Is there a way to bind my razor models that are on the page to knockout. I do not want it to be inline javascript either. It needs to be an external js file. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513725/populate-knockoutjs-view-model-object-based-on-an-initial-markup-from-the-server?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this completely in an external JavaScript file.

The best approach would to have your ViewModel defined in an external file and then following the answer from [Populate knockoutJS view model object based on an initial markup from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513725/populate-knockoutjs-view-model-object-based-on-an-initial-markup-from-the-server?rq=1).